# get value from another table based on id laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

i have two tables ( Factories , Products )

Factories table has two columns ( id , factory_name )

and Products table has three columns ( id , factory_id , product_name )

i want to display factory_name column in Factories table in blade.php based on factory_id in Products table

the code in Factory Model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

and the code in Product Model :

```
public function factories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Factory');
}
```

the code in ProductsController :

```
public function index()
{
    $data['Products'] = Product::with('factories')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
   
    return view('all_products')->with($data);
}
```

and the code in view :

```
 @foreach ($Products as $Product)
   <tr>
   <td>{{$Product->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$Product->factory_name}}</td>
   <td>{{$Product->product_name}}</td>               
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

and this not work ... so how i get factory_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a good idea to add {{dd($data)}} to blade file to see what you have.

I think the relation between products and factories is one-to-many. In this case, it would be better if you make the function name factory instead of factories.

```
public function factory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Factory');
}
```

Unless it's a correct syntax that I'm not familiar with, the problem should be $data['Products'] and with($data). Let's change them:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Product::with('factory')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();   
    return view('all_products')->with('Products', $data);
}
```

Now, you have $Products on your blade file.

Since you get factory_name through relation, factory info is associated with a key. You need this:

```
<td>{{$Product->factory->factory_name}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

its easily like this :

```
@foreach ($Products as $Product)
   <tr>
   <td>{{$Product->id}}</td>
   <td>{{$Product->factories->factory_name}}</td>
   <td>{{$Product->product_name}}</td>               
   </tr>
 @endforeach
```

since you already have a relationship called factories between your two models

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown that you are trying fetching Products along with factories

```
Product::with('factories')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

So the result that you will get from this query will be in the following format

```
{
  id: product_id,
  factories: {
     id:factory_id,
     factory_name: factory_name,
     ...
  }
}
```

So in order to fetch the factory name in products list you need to use:

```
<td>{{$Product->factories->factory_name}}</td>
```

instead of

```
<td>{{$Product->factory_name}}</td>
```

Hope this solve your problems